# Downloading data from a dataframe

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to download a dataframe from Yahoo Finance. For this I use a code below:
`import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import pandas as pd

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import pandas as pd
ticker_list = ["amzn", "aapl", "ba"]
historical_datas = {}
for ticker in ticker_list: 
    historical_datas[ticker] = si.get_data(ticker, start_date="12/04/2009", end_date="12/04/2019", index_as_date = True, interval="1mo")
historical_datas.to_csv("C:\Users\...")
```

But I have an error in output

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 9>()
      7 for ticker in ticker_list:
      8     historical_datas[ticker] = si.get_data(ticker, start_date="12/04/2009", end_date="12/04/2019", index_as_date = True, interval="1mo")
----> 9 historical_datas.to_csv("C:\\Users\\...")

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

I've tried to make a dataframe for downloading using a code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(historical_datas)
df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\...")
```

But in this situation I have an error `If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

Comment: `historical_datas` is a `dict`, not `DataFrame`. You work with `dict` of ticker:`DataFrames` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

[from_dict docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) you may use `from_dict`,to convert a dict to data frame

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way,

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(historical_datas)
```

And then you do the

```
historical_datas.to_csv(("C:\\Users\\..." , index = True)
```